# Doing Cross-platform builds with Qt Creator

Tags: qt, build-process, qt-creator

I am working on a desktop application using the Qt framework and Qt Creator IDE. I am doing my development on mac, and would like to begin testing on Windows as well. I am having trouble finding documentation on how do this. What's is the best way to develop on mac and automate windows builds of a Qt Creator project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the Qt Sdk on Windows which comes with Qt libs and Qt Creator. The Qt Creator also has c++ mingw compiler with it and hence your life is much more easier.

Note that if you doing static builds then you might have to recompile the mingw compiler with an extra flag to help create static qt builds. Just google it and you will find how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use in Windows the same Qt Creator, what is the problem?

In other case, you could download your sources on free (like sourceforge) www svn/cvs server, and used them with mac/windows/linux. For example, make some changes in your code on mac (folder *src*), after that you switched to windows, making update of sources, and do rebuild with Qt Creator, or maybe with plain qmake.exe/make.

Good luck.